# ASP.Net Core Tag Helper links ignore current culture

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, culture, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I am building a multilingual website that supports Albanian, English and Serbian ,but somehow, all the links that are generated from tag helpers keep redirecting to Serbian language.

This is what I have in `StartUp.cs`:

```
        var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
                {
                    new CultureInfo("sq-AL"),
                    new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                    new CultureInfo("sr-Latn-RS")
                };

        var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("sq-AL"),
            SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
            SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
        };
        var requestProvider = new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider();
        localizationOptions.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, requestProvider);

        app.UseRouter(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapMiddlewareRoute("{culture=sq-AL}/{*mvcRoute}", subApp =>
            {
                subApp.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);

                subApp.UseMvc(mvcRoutes =>
                {
                    mvcRoutes.MapRoute(
                        name: "default",
                        template: "{culture=sq-AL}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                });
            });
        });
```

And this is an action link that I have in the main navigation menu:

`<a asp-controller="Content" asp-action="About">@_localizer["nav_about"]</a>`

It used to work well, I tried to figure out why it's not working anymore but no idea so far.

The funny thing is that all the labels get values from resource files based on the selected culture, where as links keep redirecting to Serbian no matter what culture I switch to. The link generated from the tag helper above: `http://localhost:50807/sr-Latn-RS/Content/About`.

Same is with submit forms: `<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="RegisterProfile" method="post">` results to `http://localhost:50807/sr-Latn-RS/Account/RegisterProfile` no matter the culture currently selected.

Anyone has any idea where is it getting the Serbian culture from? Any kind of help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same problem and found the solution by setting the default culture as the first in order and specifying a constraint:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DefaultCulture",
    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}",
    constraints: new { culture = "en"},
    defaults: new { culture = "en" });
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "NonDefaultCulture",
    template: "{culture:culture=en}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
);
```

The key here is the `constraints` parameter. Without it, the tag helpers will check the first route and see it match, even though the current URL's route has a different culture. With `constraints` the algorithm will see it cannot match the current route with the constraint and will proceed with the next `NonDefaultCulture` route, which is what we need.